# access files outside node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, package

how can i access files that are outside of node_modules? what is the best way? i am making an npm package that accesses files that are outside of node modules. the package is in /root/node_modules/@scope//index.js, and i want to access a file that is in /root.
if I use path join it doesn't work well, for example, if the package is installed on a monorepo it fails to reach the files.

tree (this work)

```
.
├── node_modules/
│   └── @scope/
│       └── package/
│           └── index.js
├── file.config.js (required by the package)
├── src/
│   └── main.js (required by the package)
└── public/
    └── image.ico
```

tree (does not work)

```
.
├── node_modules/
│   └── @scope/
│       └── package/
│           └── index.js
├── my-project/
│   ├── file.config.js (required by the package)
│   ├── src/
│   │   └── main.js (required by the package)
│   └── public/
│       └── image.ico
└── package.json (monorepo)
```

try the following to try to fix it

```
// /root/node_modules/@scope/<name>/index.js
import { fileURLToPath } from "url";
import { dirname, join, resolve } from "path";

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);

const __dirname = dirname(__filename);

const dir = dirname(resolve(join(__dirname, "..", "..")));

// const dir = dirname(join(__dirname, "..", ".."));
```

Hopefully it will work fine being used inside a monorepo or being inside the root folder and being used from there.